# $Images not loaded properly on one product

Tags: prestashop

I have an old version of prestashop (1.4) and facing issue with images for a new product. In my product.tpl, the $images Array is empty (count($images) = 0), so my thumbnails does not display.

```
// Images
var img_prod_dir = '{$img_prod_dir}';
var combinationImages = new Array();

{if isset($combinationImages)}
    {foreach from=$combinationImages item='combination' key='combinationId' name='f_combinationImages'}
        combinationImages[{$combinationId}] = new Array();
        {foreach from=$combination item='image' name='f_combinationImage'}
            combinationImages[{$combinationId}][{$smarty.foreach.f_combinationImage.index}] = {$image.id_image|intval};
        {/foreach}
    {/foreach}
{/if}

combinationImages[0] = new Array();

{if isset($images)}
    //images : {$images} {count($images)}
    
    {foreach from=$images item='image' name='f_defaultImages'}
        //img - {$image.id_image}
        combinationImages[0][{$smarty.foreach.f_defaultImages.index}] = {$image.id_image};
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

I checked in prestashop database and the structure seems OK, when I play SQL request found in product.php

```
        return Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('
        SELECT i.`cover`, i.`id_image`, il.`legend`, i.`position`
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image` i
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_lang` il ON (i.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)($id_lang).')
        WHERE i.`id_product` = '.(int)($this->id).'
        ORDER BY `position`');
```

the images are loaded properly for my product.

It seems that the link between the PHP and the TPL fails somewhere, but I don't know how to look deeper between those two elements. It only occurs on one product.

What I tested :

- upload the image to another product --> it works
- upload a working image on my failed product --> same behaviour
- compare database content on ps_image, ps_product, and data seems to be the same
- checked on the FTP if images are well generated --> OK

Do you have any idea where I can look further to check what fails with my product ?

Best regards

Comment: You should check ps_product_attribute_image table also, this table keeps link between images and product variations and I'm pretty sure it exists in PS 1.4, maybe you are missing some rows there.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, unfortunately that table is empty. There is no line in this table, even for working images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue, a previous developper made an override in the folder override/controllers/ProductController.php that causes, on some really specific case, a change of product ID and the images were not loaded.

git blame is fantastic :)